# How to display an edit form as a jquery pop up modal when clicked on a link

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I am displaying information from database in a view file and there is an option to edit but its not functional yet. I want to have the edit option like this- when any user clicks on the the edit link(I am using an image as edit button) a jquery modal will pop up and show a simple edit form (and in the background it will make a query to database for information based on the clicked value).

Would you please kindly help me how to fetch the data from database and show an edit form as a jquery pop up modal when clicked on the edit link? (Please check the view file below to see the edit link)

At least an example would be highly appreciated :)

Thanks in Advance :)

Here's my View file:

```
 <article id="dashboard">

            <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
            <h1> Batch Name: <?php echo "$batchname";?> </h1>
            <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.N</th>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Exam Date</th>
                        <th>Exam Type</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Total Mark</th>
                        <th>Highest Mark</th>
                        <th>Obtained Mark</th>
                        <th>GPA</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Edit/Delete</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3) + 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>


                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>

                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>viewbatch/get/<?php echo $row['studentid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['studentid'];?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['examdate'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['examtype'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['totalmark'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['highestmark'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['obtainedmark'];?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $row['gradepoint'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['grade'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>

                        <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>updatebatch/get/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="Edit"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a>
                             <a href="#" title="Delete"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" /></a>
                             </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php  } ?>

            </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php } else { echo "No Record Found";} ?>
            <div class="tablefooter clearfix">

                        <div class="pagination">
                        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> 
                        </div>
            </div>



        </article>
```

## Edit::

Thank you mmmshuddup for your help.Actually I am aiming to show a jquery pop up modal form through which users can update data. At present in the view file I have a list of students information which I have retrieved from database. In order to let users update student information I have an edit option but at present its not in working mode. So far what you have replied is good enough but would you please kindly show me how to display data in the modal form, in between . You don't have to mention anything about the controller part, lets say I am posting the "id" to my controller and then quering the database and sending back the data to view file in a regular way. Now all I just want to know how to present the "update" form (already filled with relevant information to the user) to my user.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're going to want to add a `class` and/or `id` attribute to your edit anchor tags.

Something like this:

```
<a href="<?= base_url(); ?>updatebatch/get/<?= $row['id']; ?>" title="Edit"
    id="edit-<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="edit-link">
    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a>
```

Next, create a `div` in which to load your modal content:

```
<div id="modal-dialog"></div>
```

Now, you're ready to set up your jquery modal stuff and the `onclick` event listeners for the edit link:

```
$('#modal-dialog').dialog({
    title: 'Edit Your Item',
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'blind',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    modal: true
});

var baseUrl = "<?= base_url(); ?>updatebatch/get/";

$('.edit-link').click(function(e) {
    var id = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $('#dialog')
        .load(baseUrl + id) // or something like this
        .dialog('open');
});
```

Again, this is just an example of how you *could* do it. There are other ways to dynamically load content.  And I'm not sure what exactly you want your PHP script to do..

**Edit:**

Per OP's request, here is an example of how to fill in fields using *PHP* (not javascript):

```
<!-- assume $row is the query result array of data -->
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
<textarea name="content" id="content" rows="8" cols="50">
    <?php echo $row['content']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you mmmshuddup for your help. Would you please kindly check the edited part of my post above.?

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. But I'm not totally sure I understand what you want _me_ to do..  You want me to show you how to create a form with the fields automatically filled in with the values from an arbitrary array of data from a database or something?

Comment: Yes you understood it right. I want to learn- how to create/show the form with the fields automatically filled in with the values from an arbitrary array of data from a database, as a jquery pop up modal when clicked on the edit button . If it is very complicated thing and takes time, don't spend time on this :). And again thank you very much for your cooperation. :)

Comment: Gotcha, PHP is the better man for the job. That said, check out my latest edit. Happy coding and good luck!